# How to get full native language instead of iso?

Tags: theme-development, multisite, multi-language

I am not using WPML or Polylang, but multisite to create multiple languages. The code below is used to make a language switcher, but I want a second menu with the full language name for a different menu (i.e. EN should be English, FR - Français, DE - Deutsch). Wordpress has the native names stored (because when selecting a language you get a list with the native language name), but how can I access this to use?

```
$languages = get_available_languages();
foreach ($languages as $item) {
   $iso = substr($item, 0, 2);
   echo '<li>'. $iso .'</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost sure that you can use `locale_get_primary_language` function for that.

```
echo locale_get_primary_language( $item );
```

Maybe it'll need some tweaking, because I'm not sure if formats will match (for example you may have to change '*' to '*' or change it to lower/upper-case).

Answer (score 0):

Use this `locale_get_display_name()`